# Can you someone help me to find the indefinite integral, step by step. I did my self, and getting wrong answer.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

can you please someone tell me how to do this indefinite integral in steps
$\int$$cos(\sqrt{6x})\over\sqrt{6x}$ dx